# No "ReadFile" operation from Coldfusion server on CFM files

Tags: coldfusion, procmon

I captured a Process Monitor trace of my browser requesting a page from my local Coldfusion 8 server. I am still not very experienced in using procmon to find problems. I don't understand why I can't find any "ReadFile" operations on the CFM file I called from my browser in the trace. The file must have been read at some point since the browser received the page correctly rendered.

If I filter the trace to only include entries that have paths to CFM files, the only operations I am left with are:

- CloseFile
- CreateFile
- QueryBasicInformationFile
- QueryOpen

And it does these over and over, multiple times per file.

Answer (score 1):

The ColdFusion service would be the one doing the file read. If you lift the covers, then Its done by the JVM in which the CF runs. The reason why one cannot see the file read is because its not run as a system level unique process. ProcMon only shows you System process and tasks.

if you want to see the file read operations, may be you can try checking the [Disk Mon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896646)